# Observation axiom in probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let :

- $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measured set ($X$ is a set, $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathcal A$) where $\mu(X)=1$
- $(Y,\mathcal B)$ be a measurable set ($Y$ is a set, $\mathcal B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$)
- $f:X\to Y$ be a random variable.

Suppose I make an observation on $f$ and obtain the value $y\in Y$.

**Question :**
What's the axiom in probability theory concerning the notion of "observation" ?
i.e. what happens to $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ ?

Intuitively the measure $\mu$ should change and be vanishing on subsets of the complement of $f^{-1}(y)$. A quick guess would be that the new measure on $(X,\mathcal A)$ should, according to conditional probability, be given by :
$$
\mu'(A) = \frac{\mu(A\cap f^{-1}(y))}{\mu(f^{-1}(y))}, \quad \forall A\in \mathcal A
$$
But, if $\mu(f^{-1}(y))=0$, e.g. where I observe that the horizontal position of a random point on a $1\times 1$ sized square is $1/3$, I get a measure $\mu'(A) = 0/0$, which is undefined. That leads me to think that instead of taking a fraction I should take an $\epsilon$-wide tubular neighborhood $N_\epsilon(f^{-1}(y))$ around $f^{-1}(y)$ and then take the limit $\epsilon\to 0$, i.e. that 
$$
\mu'(A) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\mu(A\cap N_\epsilon(f^{-1}(y)))}{ \mu(N_\epsilon(f^{-1}(y)))}
$$
Is it the right way to go or is there a simpler (i.e. more abstract/axiomatic) approach ?

Comment: AFAIK, in the case of probability zero events there cannot be a *general* definition of "conditional probability" that works for every probability space; one needs additional hypotheses to be able to construct something.

Comment: Er, let me restate that. I think we can *define* "conditional property", but AFAIK a conditional probability measure need not exist. And if it does, it need not be unique.